# Asus R9 280X and three monitors

Tags: windows-7, display

Windows 7.

Two of the monitors are connected through DVI and the last monitor is connected through HDMI. The HDMI monitor doesn't receive a signal.

[image]

I've read that I need an active DisplayPort cable/adapter that costs like $100. That's almost half the price of the GPU... Do I really need to use DisplayPort?

Comment: Where have you read that you need an active DP adapter? Do the specs of the card indicate it can drive three monitors simultaneously or indicate any specific requirements for doing so?

Comment: I've been googling and it seems like I need an active DP to run the third monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need you use DisplayPort to drive a third monitor.

From this article here on Andantech -- [The Radeon R9 280X Review: Feat. Asus & XFX - Meet The Radeon 200 Series](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7400/the-radeon-r9-280x-review-feat-asus-xfx/3):

> Thanks to some firmware and board level changes, with the 200 series
>   AMD is now able to attach multiple TMDS transmitters/interfaces to the
>   same clock generator, allowing one clock generator to be used to drive
>   multiple displays. As a result it’s now possible to drive up to 3 TMDS
>   interface displays off of a single 200 series card, albeit with
>   restrictions.
>
> **The catch** here is that these can’t be independent displays, and this
>   change is primarily intended towards enabling Eyefinity with cheap,
>   DVI/HDMI-only monitors. **To utilize clock sharing and to drive 3 such
>   monitors off of a single card, all 3 monitors must be
>   timing-identical, which functionally speaking almost always requires
>   the monitors to be completely identical**. Furthermore the sharing of
>   the clock generator can only be engaged/disabled upon boot, so the 3rd
>   display cannot be hot-plugged and must be present at boot time.
>   Consequently this is by no means as unrestricted and easy as having
>   native support for 3 TMDS interface displays, but for Eyefinity it
>   will get the job done.
>
> Of course this restriction only applies to using 3 TMDS interface
>   monitors off of a single card natively. *Using the DisplayPort, either
>   with a native monitor or through an active DP-to-DVI/HDMI adapter,
>   still allows the same fully independent functionality as before*.

Comment: Ok thank you. What about the motherboard's integrated DVI port, can't I use it for the third monitor? I remember I tried it and I think I got the same issue then. I also have a second Asus R9 280X but my motherboard is an Z87-K so the second PCIE slot is only x4...